# Distinct TIME in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has this field:

```
  `processeddate` int(14) DEFAULT NULL,
```

a datetime converted by strtotime .
The content is like  `1401847266`

How do I select distinct this field which is an integer not a datetime?
I want to select per day.
Like the sum of member field ,registered, on 20140603 .

On database:

```
Member    | Processed_Date

A         | 1401847266 //real date 20140604

B         | 1401846898 //real date 20140604

C         | 1401844093   //real date 20140604

D         | 1401788219  //real date 20140603

E         | 1401788219  //real date 20140603
```

RESULT that I want to be displayed :

```
Date     | Member

20140603 | 2
20140604 | 3
```

PS.
The processeddate is in datetime format converted into time integer, not date format.

Comment: If you decide to store a date not as a date but as an integer, shouldn't you know yourself how to work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert the integer value to a datetime value and then use functions like `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` and `DAY()` on it. However when using a function on a column MySQL can't use an index anymore. Best is, to convert the other value like this:

```
...
WHERE your_column BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-04 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-04 23:59:59');
```

**EDIT:**

What you want to do can be achieved with this query:

```
select
date(from_unixtime(Processed_Date)) as date, count(*) as member
from your_table
group by date
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a378/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Hi. @fancyPants Thanks for the fast reply. I have no problem selecting with condition where but I need to distinct this integer time . I have updated my question. Is it not possible?